# Why does KLM offer this specific combination of flights (GRU -> AMS -> POZ) just on one day when there's a time change?

Tags: air-travel, klm, schedule-change

I wanted to fly KLM from São Paulo - Guarulhos to Poznań with KLM through Amsterdam. They offer this connection only on one day, 29th of October. Both connections run every day though so it does not make sense. I could fly through CDG and AMS but why can I not just fly directy to AMS? It's been bothering me for ages now.

The connection is KL792 from Brazil to Amsterdam and KL1273 from Amsterdam to Poznań.

Does anybody know why is it this way?

Comment: Could you provide the exact arrival and departure times of both flights, and the same for those flights on a different day?  My guess would be that one of the flights is scheduled based on "summer time" and the other isn't, so that on that day the connection time is one hour longer.  On ordinary days, the connection time may be too short to be "legal".

Comment: When there is a daylight saving time time change, airlines have to run a special one-day long schedule to make sure their planes end up in the right places at the right times.  Back in the days of passenger rail, North American used to stop for an hour at 2:00 am local time during the fall-back time change (and scramble like crazy during spring-forward).  Planes don't stop well, but they do have more flexibility than rail.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Daylight Savings Time change in the Netherlands .

Turns out the timing is awkward: the flight from GRU comes in at 11:45 and the one to POZ leaves at 12:10. That's not enough time to make it the same day, and taking the next day flight creates a 24+ hour layover, which the website probably doesn't allow you to book (but can be potentially booked on the phone or with an OTA).

On the night of 10/29 to 10/30, the Netherlands switches back to standard time. You  gain an hour and the GRU flight comes in at 10:40. That's early enough to make the connection

Comment: I just looked it up on the KLM website, and starting 10/30, the flight leaves GRU about one hour later, arriving in AMS at 11:40, which is why the connection only works on one single day and not every day throughout winter. Anyone has any idea why they don't start their "winter schedule" one day earlier?

Comment: @Sabine presumably the plane is based in Amsterdam and it's easier for them to deal with the time change by moving whole round-trips starting and ending there than it is to adjust the length of time that the plane is on the ground in Brazil.

Comment: Ok, I see I made a mistake in my research. The flight to Poznań used to leave a lot later, sometime around 13h30-14h00 so there was at least 1,5hrs of a change, now starting September it leaves at 12h10 and the flight from GRU arrives at 11h45. Even though there was plenty of time for a change this connection would not be allowed. Now I can see that this flight is allowed whenever there's enough time.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks.

TL:DR: My mistake.